# Вывод дополнительных данных в Layouts (Yii)

Tags: bootstrap, yii, php

Для некоторых страниц своего приложения мне хотелось бы использовать двухколончатый шаблон.
Для этого я хотел бы просто использовать другой **layout**.

В новом **layout** кроме переменной **$content**, которая выводит содержимое конкретного **view**, мне бы хотелось выводить еще другие данные, в другой колонке. Вот код нового layout:

```
<?php /* @var $this AdminController */ ?>
<?php $this->beginContent('/layouts/main'); ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
         <!-- Any data -->
      </div>
      <div class="span8">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

И вот как раз, где **Any data**, мне хотелось бы выводить другую **не шаблонную инфу** (например, форму редактирования или список свойств, постоянно меняющихся в зависимости от  ID просматриваемой записи).

**UPDATE:** 
Если выводить переменную **$any_date**, вместо Any date. То, как туда записывать данные из view, такие как: widget и прочее. Неужели добавляя к строке просто html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Controller extends CController{
    public $additional;
    ...   
}
```

---

```
class MainController extends Controller{
    public function actionFoo(){
        $this->additional = $this->renderPartial('viewName', $data, true /* Вернуть результат, а не вывести*/);

        ...
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php $this->beginContent('/layouts/main'); ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
         <?php if(!empty($this->additional)) echo $this->additional;?>
      </div>
      <div class="span8">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Круто! Сейчас буду пробовать, это кажется именно то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Если чесно, это первое, что пришло в голову))
Но хранить кучу HTML кода в переменной не есть гут.

Как еще один бредовый вариант - в additional хранить массив типа 
array(
    'FirstWidgetName' => array('widgetParam' => 'widgetValue'...),
    'SecondWidget' => array(...)
);

А "собирать" HTML все таки в layout

Comment: @dekameron, но почему это не гут? Это, своего рода костыль?

Comment: @frops, Вся переменная хранится в памяти, а это достаточно много места

Comment: Да, не очень хорошо. Но, если учесть, что это админка сайта, вывод будет около 10-20 Кб, нагрузка будет не большой то ок, да? А если делать на страницах  с высокой нагрузкой и большим количеством запросов, то будет все очень плохо, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @frops, все правильно, чем больше данных будет в переменной и чем больше будет юзверей - тем всё становится печальней.


Альтернативный вариант я описал выше, сделать чтото типа коллектора, который будет принимать данные и уже на их основе вызывать нужные виджеты в нужном порядке

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $this->beginContent('/layouts/main'); ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
          <?php echo $any_data; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="span8">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Передавай еще одну переменную в шаблон и все.

Comment: Так как эту переменную формировать, если я хочу там использовать виджеты, и прочее?

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такой вариант, в макете пишем:

```
<?php /* @var $this AdminController */ ?>
  <?php $this->beginContent('/layouts/main'); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <!-- Any data -->
          <?php 
            if (!empty($this->clips['content2'])) 
              echo $this->clips['content2'];
          ?>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
          <?php echo $content; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

В шаблоне:

```
<?php $this->beginClip('content2') ?>
    <h1>Содержимое для области content2</h1>
<?php $this->endClip() ?>
```

Если нужно ещё что то более сложное то можно использовать шаблонизаторы вроде twig.